# Include .h path in windows but omit in unix in visual studio

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, unix, dirent.h

I want to include dirent.h in my visual studio project. I wish to have compatibility both with unix and windows. That is why I am considering using https://github.com/tronkko/dirent . In that project, the documentation says:

> If you wish to distribute dirent.h alongside with your own source
>   code, then copy include/dirent.h file to a new sub-directory within
>   your project and add that directory to include path on Windows while
>   omitting the directory under Linux/UNIX. This allows your project to
>   be compiled against native dirent.h on Linux/UNIX while substituting
>   the functionality on Microsoft Windows.

which are the steps to do that in visual studio? (I am using 2017 version but I suppose that it will be similar to older versions)

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio but not any other build system, your code can't be automatically compiled on UNIX at all. A decent recommendation would be CMake, but of course please do your own researches and do not ask opinion based questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Use the properties sheet for the project.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi Visual Studio 2017 now supports compiling C++ projects for Linux.

Comment: Just use `#include <filesystem>`. That's _way_ easier than `dirent`, although it does require C++17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A classical solution used to differentiate #includes is to use preprocessor directives such as #if or #ifdef.

For example, you can use:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#include "stuff specific to Microsoft Visual Studio"
#else
#include "stuff not specific for Microsoft Visual Studio"
#endif
```

in your case, you may want something like:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#include "msvc/dirent.h"
#else
#include <dirent.h>
#endif
```